# Xamarin.Android keep session logged

Tags: android, xamarin, facebook-login, google-signin

how I can keep my application logged Xamarin.Android with facebook, google, Active Directory etc. Do not ask me to start each time the application runs

Answer (score 0):

Use Xamarin Auth plugin.You can keep user data in AcccounStore which persists between app runs. How often user gets logged out depends on the provider (Facebook, Google, etc) If provider supports not expiring access_token just use it all the time. If provider doesn't support that then use refresh_token